# Limit listview, and display letters only

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I have a listview that is displayed to the user, and I am figuring out ways to make the listview non-infinite, and limit it to 25 items. I am also trying restrict user from being able to display a number in the EditText. I have tried to add         android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" , in list view but this has proven to be ineffective.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/white_wallpaper"
                >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/message_left" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/off_white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage" />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="@string/message_elipses"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#adefda"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iSchedule"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="#C11B17"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

As far as limiting listview items, I have the below code:
Below is how the listview is displayed programmatically:

```
 messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
```

WOuld the below work:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        return 25;
    }
```

Comment: By "trying restrict user from being able to display a number in the EditText", do you mean you don't want the user to be able to enter numbers into the field? It would help if you could clear that up.

Comment: Ah yes thats what I mean. I do not want users to be able to enter numbers into the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to handle your edit text problem, you can use this

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
/>
```

Now the above characters are the only one that can be entered into the EditText. Also you can change the keyboard type in the [`android:inputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).
Additionally you wanted to limit the number of entries in a ListView. In the BaseAdapter method of your code, change this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 25;
}
```

UPDATE:

Well what you can do is create a custom [ArrayAdapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_defaultadapter) and modify the getCount method there. As `getCount()` is in a different class altogether, you just want to alter the maximum **25** there and then set the list view to that adapter. You may want to take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for more uses of ArrayAdapters.

Comment: thank you for your prompt update. I have resolve the first issue with edittext. As far as the listview goes, I have added an uodate under my initial post

Comment: any assitance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I also notice with the first EditText criteria, it does not allow spacing. it has succesfully resolve my issue with not having numbers, but for some reason it does not include spacing. Would you by chance have a fix? Thank you so much

Comment: Your help was tremendous, and I truly appreciate your support. I am just having an issue resolving the limitation of items on the list for this is how I declare the list -  messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);\